# Какой код соответствует tab?

Tags: кодировка

В программе используют такие коды клавиш:

```
0..9 : 48..57
A..Z : 65..90
A : 65
B : 66
C : 67
D : 68
E : 69
F : 70
G : 71
H : 72
I : 73
J : 74
K : 75
L : 76
M : 77
N : 78
O : 79
P : 80
Q : 81
R : 82
S : 83
T : 84
U : 85
V : 86
W : 87
X : 88
Y : 89
Z : 90
ALT : 18
CONTROL : 17
DOWN : 40
UP : 38
LEFT : 37
RIGHT : 39
ENTER : 10
ESCAPE : 27
DELETE : 127
SHIFT : 16
SPACE : 32
F1 : 112
F2 : 113
F3 : 114
F4 : 115
F5 : 116
F6 : 117
F7 : 118
F8 : 119
F9 : 120
F10 : 121
F11 : 122
F12 : 123
```

Какой код соответствует tab ?

Comment: 9 *(14 символов нужно...)*

Comment: @Igor, увы нет. По ASCII я сразу проверил. В ASCII  enter -13, а тут -10

Comment: @Hardc0re увы, нет. В ASCII 13 это возврат каретки. А новая строка таки 10.

Comment: @Igor, да вы правы что-то я невнимательно посмотрел.